# How to solve the inequality with logarithm?

Tags: inequality, logarithms, fractions

The inequality is: $$\frac{1}{\log_{(x-1)}\frac{x}{20}}\ge-1$$

I made a plot of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\log_{(x-1)}\frac{x}{20}}+1$ and it looks the answer is $x\in(1,5]\cup(20,+\infty)$. Using logarithm definition I conclude that the argument $\frac{x}{20}>0$, the base $x-1>0$ and $x-1\ne1$. Also I made a couple of transformations of initial inequality to retrieve definite answer but it doesn't quite match what I see on the plot.

I am looking for a specific solution steps required to get the answer.

Comment: **Hint:** Assuming that by $\log_{(a)}(b)$ you denote the logarithm of $b$ in base $a$, express $\log_{(a)}(b)$ in terms of the natural logarithms ($\ln$) of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I made all standard transformations, what I am struggle with is specific details on how to get an answer that matches the one that got from the plot. Or if it's incorrect how to get the correct one. Can you describe all solution steps?

Comment: Please see how my answer fits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by KM101 and myself:
$$
\log_ab = \frac{\ln b}{\ln a}
$$
Then your inequality is equivalent to:
$$
\frac{\ln (x-1)}{\ln\frac{x}{20}} \geq -1
$$

Note that we must have $x\neq20$ and $x>1$ for all those quantities to exist.

Now, there are two cases to consider:

- $\ln\frac{x}{20} > 0$ ie. $\frac{x}{20}>1$ and then:
  $$
  \ln(x-1) \geq \ln\frac{20}{x}
  $$
  (we already set $x>1$ so $x\neq 0$)

and by applying $x\mapsto e^x$ (which is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$) on each side:
$$
x-1\geq \frac{20}{x}
$$

No need to do much more here since we have $\frac{x}{20}>1$ ie. $x>20$, the former inequallity is always verified ($x-1>19$ and $\frac{20}{x}<1$). Thus, the inequality holds for all $x>20$.

- $\ln\frac{x}{20} < 0$ ie. $\frac{x}{20}<1$ and then:
  $$
  \ln(x-1) \leq \ln\frac{20}{x}
  $$

and by applying $x\mapsto e^x$ (which is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$) on each side:
$$
x-1\leq \frac{20}{x}
$$
which yields
$$
x^2 - x -20 \leq 0
$$
$-4$ and $5$ are obvious roots (if not use standard methods to find them). Then the sign of the polynomial is easy to find: it is positive or zero for $x\leq-4$ and $x\geq5$ and negative or zero for $-4\leq x\leq5$. What matters for us given the inequality is the latter case. But from former hypotheses, we must also have $x>1$ and $x<20$. Thus, the inequality holds for $1<x\leq 5$.

In the end, the two distinct cases indeed yield $x\in (1,5]\cup(20,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use

$$\log_a b = \frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$$

which yields

$$\frac{1}{\frac{\ln \frac{x}{20}}{\ln (x-1)}} \geq -1$$

and the inequality can be solved simply from here onward.

Comment: I made all standard transformations, what I am struggle with is specific details on how to get an answer that matches the one that got from the plot. Or if it's incorrect how to get the correct one. Can you describe all solution steps?